# Echo web framework and its analogues

Tags: java, web

There is this Java Web applications framework, [Echo](http://echo.nextapp.com/site/), which is very different from any MVC frameworks, and even MVC approach. It's still a framework for building server applications, unlike GWT.

First, I'm wondering if there is a name for frameworks like Echo (I would call Spring an MVC framework, for example, but I don't know what to call Echo).

Second, I'm wondering if there are any other alternatives that follow the same approach. Whether they are based on Java or not. I couldn't come up with any search query that would help me find those.

Answer (score 1):

Echo is still an MVC framework (it uses the Swing object model, and Swing is definitely MVC). Web frameworks are divided into action-based and component-based varieties, where Spring MVC is action-based, and Echo, Tapestry, Wicket, and JSF are component-based.

Action-based frameworks emphasize controllers that respond to urls. The user implements controllers that are called by the framework when a url is requested. The application deals directly with urls, http requests and responses, and the http session.

Component-based frameworks introduce abstractions for pages and widgets and events, so the user creates components and writes event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Echo is a component based framework as compare to MVC. [Apache Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) is a typical component based framework. Another famous component oriented framework is [Apache Tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/)